# Error en el codigo de alineación y color

Tags: html, css

No entiendo por que no me funciona la alineación de texto y el color del mismo, lo he intentado de diferentes formas usando comillas y sin comillas, también usé igual y el porcentaje y tampoco funciona.

Ayuda por favor.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>París</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor"#BEABD7">
    <Center>
    <table width"75%"  height"75%">
    <h1 align="center">Francia</h1>
    <h2><u><b> París </b></u></h2>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te falta un `=` entre cada atributo y su valor: `width="75%"` por ejemplo

Answer (score 3):

- De acuerdo con *canIuse.com*<sup>1</sup>, la propiedad **`bgcolor`** esta obsoleta y ya no deberías usarla.
- No uses etiquetas como **`u`** o **`b`** para aplicar estilos al texto directo en tu HTML, en su lugar usa las propiedades CSS destinadas a ello, como puedes revisar en el ejemplo
- Tu marcado HTML para la tabla esta incompleto, al menos para la parte de los encabezados deberías usar **`tr-th`** acompañado de **`thead`**
- Cómo el punto anterior no está bien hecho por eso el tema de porcentajes no se aplica correctamente

Tu código:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>París</title>
</head>
<style>
  h2{
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  body{
    background: tomato;
  }
  table{
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
  }
</style>
<body>
<Center>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><h1>Francia</h1></th>
    <th><h2>París</h2></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Referencias**

- [CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=bgcolor)

Answer (score 1):

No sé si lo que quieres es darle color al texto o al fondo/contendor en que se encuentra, en cualquier caso la manera en que lo haces no es la más idónea. Los estilos deberían ir a parte en una hoja de estilos. Para darle color al texto tienes que dárselo a su etiqueta, en este caso `H1` y `H2` con "color:" y si es al fondo será con `background-color:`, en cuanto a la alineación un `text-align: center` te bastará:

```css
.anchoAlto {
  width:75%;
  height:75%
}
h1 {
  text-align: center; 
  color:red; 
  background-color:blue
}
h2 {
  text-align: center; 
  color:orange; 
  background-color:green;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:underline
}
```

```html
<div class="anchoAlto">
  <h1>Francia</h1>
  <h2>París</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas con `css`, te quitas de problemas y es más fácil de implementar y ser leído por cualquier navegador.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>París</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    table{width:75%;,height:75%;}
    body{background-color:#BEABD7;}
    h1{text-align:center;}
  </style>
  <body>
    <Center>
    <table>
    <h1>Francia</h1>
    <h2><u><b> París </b></u></h2>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar estilos en línea debes definirlos dentro del atributo `style` de `HTML` como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>París</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#BEABD7;">
    <table style="width:75%; height:75%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color:black;">
          <h1 style="color:white; text-align:center;">Francia</h1>
          <h2><u><b> París </b></u></h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

No es muy recomendable hacerlo de este modo si tu proyecto es grande por que tendrías que repetir los mismos estilos en cada etiqueta, pero es igual de válido que usarlos en hojas de estilos `CSS` *Cascade Style Sheet*.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que buscas:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>París</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#BEABD7">
    <Center>
      <table width"75%"  height"75%">
        <h1>Francia</h1>
        <h2><u><b> París </b></u></h2>
        <br>
      </table>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo que buscas se parece a esto, he arreglado tus etiquetas para que entiendan los comandos de estilo que le habías pedido. Espero que sirva de ayuda.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>París</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor"#BEABD7">
    <Center>
    <table style="width:75%; height:75%">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Francia</h1>
    <h2><u><b> París </b></u></h2>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lo que he cambiado es:
·          para que la etiqueta pueda leer tus estilos primero necesitas indicarselo con un Style="_tus estilos separados con punto y como"

· h1 style="text-align:center">Francia  Lo mismo del paso anterior pero cambiando tu estilo por un "text-align:center" que como su nombre indica te colocará el texto en medio de su contenedor padre.

Comment: Puedes añadir a tu respuesta que fue lo que cambiaste y porque? :)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo creo que te faltan los signos "=" para asignar los valores a loas atributos, por otro lado no estoy seguro de que buscas pero usas etiquetas de sobra como por ejeemplo una tabla que nunca la cerraste. recuerda siempre cerrar las etiquetas.

Te recomiendo leer sobre html en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>París</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#BEABD7">
    <h1 align="center">Francia</h1>
    <h2 align="center">París</h2>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```